# Outlook attachment source file path

Tags: outlook, attachment, filepath

I am using Outlook.Attachment attachment object in my C# Outlook AddIn. But the attachment object doesn't have any field which suggest what is the full source path of the file being attached.

The attachment object has the following fields/methods, but they are not helpful.

- attachment.DisplayName
- attachment.FileName
- attachment.GetTemporaryFilePath()

Comment: How about showing some code?  This may explain things better...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing - attachment does not have to come from the file system even it is created. After its is inserted, it is stored outside of the file system alongside messages in the store.